# Swift Firebase check if email is already in use

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to be able to check if an email address is already been used (so if somebody put test1@test.com but another user already registered with that email account).

I have a simple test if it has NOT been used an image view shows a green arrow, if it HAS been used then it is red x

when I create the user I use the following code

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

    if error == nil {

      self.ref.child("userEmails").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(email)


      FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: email,
                             password: password)

    } else {
      //registration failure
    }
```

what I am trying to do to check is

```
func checkIfEmailExists(textField: UITextField) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let email = firstContainerTextField.text ?? ""

    ref.child("userEmails").queryEqual(toValue: email)
      .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if (self.firstContainerTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
          self.firstContainerImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "emptyBlue.png")

        } else if !(self.firstContainerTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && !snapshot.exists() {
          self.firstContainerImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "redEx.png")

        } else if snapshot.exists() {
          self.firstContainerImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "greenCheck.png")
        }

    });

}
```

So far it does not work as I can see in my database that test1@test.com exists. 
Can somebody tell me what I missed?

**EDIT**

I have updated my code. I am using hasChildren and I searched for similar questions and they seem to point this direction, but I still cannot get the result I am looking for

```
func checkIfEmailExists(textField: UITextField) {

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

let email = firstContainerTextField.text ?? ""

ref.child("userEmails").queryEqual(toValue: email)
  .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    if !snapshot.hasChildren() {

      self.firstContainerImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "redEx.png")

    } else {

      for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

        let tmp = child.value as! String


        if tmp == email {

          self.firstContainerImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "greenCheck.png")

        }

      }
    }

  });
}
```

**Edit 2**

I changed how I set my user up

```
self.ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["Email": email])
```

so now my database looks like this

```
users
    *****uid*****
        Email: "test@test.com
```

Comment: When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. If there are no result, you'll get an empty list. You'll want to check `snapshot.hasChildren()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-haschildren

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I read that document and saw the snapshot.hasChild(String) ...when I used that and typed in the email I get a crash saying    (hasChild:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Comment: I linked to `hasChildren()` (plural), not to `hasChild()` (which takes a string argument to indicate what child to check for).

Answer (score 1):

The following is the structure of the [Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(im)fetchProvidersForEmail:completion:) you might be looking for (Swift 4):

```
Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: emailAddress, completion: {
        (providers, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let providers = providers {
            print(providers)
        }
    })
```

If the email address is already registered to a user, you will get a list of the providers that the email address is used for. Otherwise, the list of providers will be empty, and thus the email address is not registered.

Comment: Auth.auth().fetchProviders does not exist anymore. Is there a newer version of that function?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented earlier: you'll need to check whether the query has any results by calling `snapshot.hasChildren()`.

```
func checkIfEmailExists(textField: UITextField) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let email = firstContainerTextField.text ?? ""

    ref.child("userEmails").queryEqual(toValue: email)
      .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            // User doesn't exist yet...
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I have tried that in combination with other SO answers and I still cannot seem to get it to work.