# Swift Firebase Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is a follow up to my previous question. I am trying to see if an email has already been used.

I am using the line

```
if snapshot.hasChild(email) {
```

I have in my database an email test1@test.com
When I type that in..the moment I get to the '.' before com the app crashes and gives an error that says this

```
Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'
```

I see a lot of posts about checking for usernames, but my app doesn't have usernames, just email. Am I able to use email with

```
hasChild(...) {...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase keys cannot contain a `.` (dot) character. If you want to store an email address in a key, you'll have to encode it. The common way to do that is to replace the `.` with a `,` (comma), which conveniently is not allowed in email addresses. So `test1@test.com` would be encoded as `test1@test,com`.

I don't think you're actually storing the email address as a key, but I'll follow up for that on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372354/swift-firebase-check-if-email-is-already-in-use).