# Can we have Email Id as key in Firebase database?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a login system , when the user logs in, based 
on the logged in users email id, I want to retrieve the EID.

The JSON structure I want is:

```
{
  "joel@dept.com":
       {
            "EID":"0153"
        },
   "Stan@dept.com":
       {
               "EID":"0163"
        }
}
```

I tried importing the JSON file with above structure into the Firebase projects database, but got an error suggesting "./ ..." cannot be a part of key.

Comment: "ECMAScript can be used like foo['bar'] and foo.bar" can you explain please

Comment: keys in firebase will be part of url hence validation's for url must apply

Comment: Invalid key characters (of which `.` is one) are listed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20363114/6680611).

Comment: If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Comment: Joel: you can't use `.` in Firebase Database keys, so that is typically encoded to a `,` (which handily cannot occur in an email address).
@Dai: `var object = { "bla@doo.com": "value" }` is valid. The fact that you can't use dot notation on it, doesn't make it invalid.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372563/swift-firebase-must-be-a-non-empty-string-and-not-contain-or/41372697#41372697

Answer (score 6):

Replacing one character with another may lead to confusion and may cause critical issues in future.

For the instance, replacing `.` with `_DOT_` may work for now. Say in future you want to get back the original email for some verification; [no big deal] I can replace `_DOT_` back with `.`. This fails if someone has the email `actual._DOT_@actualdot.com`

The solution is to use email hash. I prefer md5 at the moment.

So the structure should be:

```
{
    "<md5 hash of 'joel@dept.com'>": { 
            "EID":"0153" 
     }, 
    "<md5 hash of 'Stan@dept.com'>": { 
             "EID":"0163" 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Should be marked as answer.

Comment: Can you guide me how to use md5 moment in firebase project?

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same constraints and i replaced '.' with '__dot__' to make email id as a key.

Comment: I went ahead with firebase key itself and changed the code

Comment: you have no way of knowing whether `h__dot__x@gmail__dot__com` stands for `h.x@gmail.com` or `h__dot__x@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not support characters like .[]{} hence if you want to produce in using the email as the primary key then you will have to replace the .replace(".",",")