# How can I use user input to name a child in Firebase?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a simple user database on Firebase for iOS. I have two textfields, one that takes the user's email address, and the other that takes the user's password. I want the email to be the user's uid. I try to accomplish this by creating a variable called "email" which I set equal to emailTextField.text! Then I implement the code that generates child(s) in Firebase, like so:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("users").child(email).setValue(true)
```

Here's my problem: creating a child and naming it using a variable, doesn't work. I can do the following just fine:

```
ref.child("users").child("email")
```

but once I take away the quotation marks around "email" so that it becomes the variable, the program crashes. 
How can I use user input to name a child in Firebase?

Comment: What error are you getting? (Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41372563/4916627) for a common problem with using emails as keys in Firebase)

Comment: @AndréKoolThank you for your help! I'm just getting a generic error though. "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException", and "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Have you looked at Firebase Auth email/password authentication ?  It could make your life a lot easier. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth

Comment: @rbaldwin Yes, that's what I'm using

Comment: Without knowing your exact use case, you could store users in a collection using their uid as the document reference.  If you really need to store the email and password you could save that as a field in that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase node / document names do not support the same character set which email addresses support, for example, the . symbol in an email address would make the child name invalid.

If you tried setting a child as
`ref.child("users").child("xyz@xyz.xyz")`
you should see the same error.

If you absolutely need to use the email address as the node name, I recommend encoding the email in a way which is compatible with the firebase node name rules.

[Link to the rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree)

Edit: If you are using firebase auth, the normal pattern is too use the UID returned by the authenticated user object as the node name, not the email address entered from the textfield.

A quick example:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  if let user = user {
        ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(true)
  }
}
```