# Is it possible to accept email as key in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an web application and I need to store emails as a key. Is there any way to do it, instead of setting names?

[image: JSON Object]

Comment: You might want to edit your question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, and what you're trying to avoid in a solution.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database keys can't contain `.`, which is a valid (and required) character in email addresses. The common workaround is to replace the `.` with a `,`, which is not allowed in an email address but *us* allowed in a Firebase key. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713039/can-we-have-email-id-as-key-in-firebase-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372563/swift-firebase-must-be-a-non-empty-string-and-not-contain-or

Answer (score 1):

No and yes. The dot is an illegal character for the RTD. So you can replace it

```
variable key = some@email.com.yourLanguageReplace(".", "DOT");
```

And then use that as a key

```
wBookingsRef.child(variable).set(...
```

The result should be:

```
-webBookings
 -some@emailDOTcom: {}
```